# Application Support vs GKSavedGame

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud, game-center

Right now, I'm developing a game for mobile. On the iOS version of my game I store the local savegame within the Application Support folder in the app data. This folder will be synced with the iCloud when it's enabled (which is enabled by default), see the [iOS Storage Best Practices at Tech Talks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/) (3:45).

Now, I'm implementing Game Center into my app, thus I stomped over the [GKSavedGame class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gksavedgame) that seem to be store my savegame in the iCloud, too.

What is the difference between those two?

If I use both, will the user end up with duplicated data in his/her iCloud?

What is the correct route to go here?